# Use Alt_L as Space

Tags: xmodmap

My old laptop's keyboard has a dead <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

I have found that with the commands:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Space"
xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Alt_L"
```

I can do the job,as I  have to map the space to it's nearest key, thus to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and then to remap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

My question is, how can I run it on every boot? Also, I created a .sh file with these two commands, to execute in my desktop but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec="</path/to/script>"
Hidden=true
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Modify keyboard map
```

and place it to `$HOME/.config/autostart`

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I managed to do the job by putting the line

`Exec=xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = space"`
but if i place the second Exec like
`Exec=xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Alt_L"`
then in some way it cancels the first.
Should I place it in another file or what?

Comment: This line should work: `Exec=sh -c "xmodmap -e 'keysym Alt_L = space' && xmodmap -e 'keysym Super_L = Alt_L'"` , but I recommend you to use this commands in shell script and place this script in /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 2):

With this solution, your new <kbd>Space</kbd> is <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> and your old <kbd>Space</kbd> is <kbd>Left Super</kbd>

1. Search for the right keycodes with:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke | grep Alt_L
   ```

   *Sample output*

   ```
   keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
   keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
   ```

   and

   ```
   xmodmap -pke | grep Super_L
   ```

   *Sample output*

   ```
   keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
   keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
   ```
2. Open the file `~/.Xmodmap`

   ```
   nano ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
3. Place your mappings, eg.:

   ```
   keycode  64 = space
   keycode 133 = Alt_L
   ```

   in this file and test it with

   ```
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
4. Then open the file `~/.xinitrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.xinitrc
   ```

   and add this lines

   ```
   if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
       xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   fi
   ```

   If `~/.xinitrc` does not work then use `~/.profile`
5. Log out and log in again.